# firebase onDisconnectSetValue not working as expected

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

maybe I understand firebase's onDisconnectSetValue wrong, but I expect the following:
In firebase I have a value "active" which is true, if the app is connected with the firebase. I like to use onDisconnectSetValue to set the value to false, if the connection is lost.
To test it I do the following:
- Start app with internet connection (set wlan on)
- App sets "Active" to true
- Now I cut internet connection (set wlan off)

Now I expect that firebase automatically sets "Active" to false, but the value stays true.

Strange thing is, that "Active" is set to false, if I reconnect to internet (set wlan on again).

Code:

```
Firebase *userAppActiveRef = [Firebase userAppActiveRef: user.entityID];
Firebase *infoRef = [Firebase infoRef];
[infoRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    if([snapshot.value boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"connected");
        [userAppActiveRef setValue: @YES];
        [userAppActiveRef onDisconnectSetValue: @NO];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not connected");
    }
}];
```

infoRef = .../.info/connected

What do I wrong or is onDisconnectSetValue not working the way I think?

Comment: If you forcefully drop the connection (as opposed to calling `goOffline()`), the server will detect that the client has disappeared after the socket times out. This usually takes a few minutes. How long did you wait?

Comment: about 5 - 20 minutes (4 tries).
As I mentioned, it is strange that the value changes after I reconnect to internet. It is independent how long I wait.
Is there a possibility to set the socket time out? Or where can I see which time is set for time out?

Answer (score 1):

Try this slightly different direction (this is an expanded version of most of the code you posted)

There are two parts to this. Part 1 is the app knowing if itself is connected or not (and taking action either way) and Part 2 is knowing if other users are connected or not:

```
    //keep track if the app is connected to firebase or not via isConnected 
    //  isConnected has KVO listeners in the classes so they can take
    //  action when the user disconnects or reconnects

    Firebase *connectedRef = [self.appRef childByAppendingPath:@".info/connected"];

    [connectedRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        //KVO property will change if the app d/c's        
        self.isConnected = [snapshot.value boolValue]; 

        if ( self.isConnected ) {
            NSLog(@"connected");
            [thisUserStatusRef setValue:@"YES"];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"d/c'd!! Run for the hills!");
        }

    }];
```

With this setup, the app knows when it's connected and will set thisUsersStatusRef to YES.

Then, set the onDisconnect to take action when the user disconnects

```
[thisUserStatusRef onDisconnectRemoveValue];
```

This tells the server to remove thisUsersStatusRef when the that client disconnects (you could set to NO as well).

So when the user connects, thisUsersStatusRef is set to YES and when it disconnects, the value is removed.

Finally, have your app observe the Users node for any changes - if another user connects the app will be notified and if they disconnect, they will also be notified.

```
[usersRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildChanged withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

   //the snapshot will contain the user that connected or disconnects
   //  so just test to see if status is YES or null

 }];
```

Comment: @MJQZ1347 There are a few differences, note that my answer states *this is an expanded version of most of the code you posted*. First there's an example of setting up a reference to the node that monitors the connection. Next, we've added a KVO variable that other parts of the app can observe for automatic updates to the disconnects. So for example, that variable could be kept in the app delegate. Other classes can then observe that variable and when user disconnects, can take action. Also, a snippet so we can observe if other users connect or disconnect.